# How do I pass props callback to a Route?

Tags: reactjs

In my parent App.js file I have :

```
<Route path="/login" component={Login} onFormSubmit={this.onLoginSubmit} />
```

But in Login.js when I do :

```
this.props.onFormSubmit(this.state.email, this.state.password);
```

I get : **TypeError: this.props.onFormSubmit is not a function**

EDIT : I see that this is a workaround :

```
<Route path="/login" render={(props) => (<Login onFormSubmit={this.onLoginSubmit} {...props} />)} />
```

Or this the only / right way to get this working like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use render props like this.

```
<Route
  path='/login'
  render={(props) => (
    <Login onFormSubmit={this.onLoginSubmit}  />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured by looking at other SO similar questions' answers, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using `react-router-dom` here. In that case, the `Route` component injects only three properties to the component property, `Login`.

You may refer to https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props, but basically only the following values will be exposed (i.e. injected) by `Route` to the `Login` component:

**[match](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/match)**

> A match object contains information about how a  matched the URL

**[location](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location)**

> Locations represent where the app is now, where you want it to go, or even where it was

**[history](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history)**

> The term “history” and "history object" in this documentation refers to the history package, which is one of only 2 major dependencies of React Router (besides React itself), and which provides several different implementations for managing session history in JavaScript in various environments

Hence, passing an arbitrary property value like `onFormSubmit` will not work since `Route` does not inject it into the child component. That's the reason why you're getting the *TypeError*. If you really need to expose `this.onLoginSubmit`, I suggest you use React context, aside from the answer by Nilesh that uses render props.